# Prevent class from being allocated in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, memory

I'm wondering how it is possible to create a class in Objective-C that cannot be allocated (or init)?

I'm trying to replicate the SKDownload Apple class (StoreKit framework) and I noticed that the documentation doesn't mention any alloc or init methods.
This may be missing in the documentation but present in the code ? (some .h declaration missing to prevent us from using this method?). I've tried to +alloc-init this class and either alloc and init return null.

What I'm trying to achieve is a class B that possesses only getters, that can only be created by a class A (just like factory methods would do - only A can create and return B instances, but the user cannot create B directly).

Example:

```
@interface A : NSObject
// Only A "+createB" class method can create B instances
+ (Second *)createBWithValue:(int)value;
@end

@interface B : NSObject
- (id)init; // return nil
+ (id)alloc; // return nil
- (int)value; // this returns the value passed from A
@end
```

**Question 1:** How would you proceed to create such classes? Is is possible ?

**Question 2:** How can - (int)value on B return the value passed in the class method in A? (knowing that +alloc, -init and/or other memory allocation methods may be nullified since users cannot create B classes directly - also custom initWithValue methods in B may be unavailable too)

I'm a little confused on how the Apple engineers do that..are there hidden methods that Apple doesn't want me to use?

Thanks you.

Comment: Many hidden methods they don't want you to use. Have you done any experimentation? What did you find out?

Comment: `@implementation Foo +(id) alloc { return nil; } @end`

Comment: Thanks H2CO3, but this doesn't answer any of my 2 questions. I'm already aware of this hack and this is want I would have done. But using this trick, how can Apple return me perfectly valid allocated SKDownload instances?

Comment: @Nicolas `class_createInstance([SKDownload class], 0)`

Comment: Side note: `SKDownload` *does* have `alloc` and `init` methods—Apple's class documentation just excludes inherited methods.

Comment: Yep, the absence of alloc/init in the docs does not indicate that those should not be used.  Apple docs pretty much always omit inherited methods with no new semantics.  Eg, NSDateFormatter doesn't list alloc or init, but you certainly must use those to use the class.

Comment: So this means that if I were to investigate the SKDownload methods, I would certainly find a custom hidden initializer right?

Comment: @Nicolas: Not necessarily. There is a different designated initializer (`initWithXPCEncoding:`), as seen here: https://gist.github.com/mdippery/49eb8e548784982c668f But again, there's also an `alloc` and `init` method that do what you would expect (that is, return an instance of the class).

Comment: @mipadi, thanks. How did you manage to get this list of method? Introspection?

Comment: @Nicolas: The `nm` tool: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed that the documentation doesn't mention any alloc or init methods

From the documentation:

> *Your app never directly creates a SKDownload object. Instead, after a payment is processed, your app reads the transaction object’s
> downloads property to retrieve an array of SKDownload objects
> associated with the transaction.*
>
> are there hidden methods that Apple doesn't want me to use?

**Yes.** There are a great many hidden methods that Apple doesn't want you to use.

So, the idea is that you're not supposed to create instances of `SKDownload` yourself, and for that reason the initialization method isn't part of the public API. That doesn't mean that there isn't a way to create `SKDownload` instances, just that there's not a public way for *you* to create them.

It's pretty common for classes to limit allocation or initialization. Singleton classes, for example, will often override `+allocWithZone:` such that it only allocates a new object if one hasn't already been created; if one exists, it returns that object instead (and the initializer basically does nothing).

**Hide the initializer.**

If you want to create a class like that yourself, override the inherited initialization method(s) (probably just `-init`) so that they return `nil` or maybe even throw an exception. Implement your own initializer, but keep it out of the public interface for the class:

```
// B.h
@interface B : NSObject
@property(readonly) int value;
@end;

// B.m
@interface B ()
@property(readwrite) int value;
-(id)secretInitializerWithValue:(int)v;
@end

@implementation B
-(id)secretInitializerWithValue:(int)v
{
    if ((self == [super init])) {   // not really necessary since NSObject's -init doesn't do anything
        _value = v;
    }
}

-(id)init
{
     @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Don't do that!" 
                                    reason:@"You shouldn't instantiate B yourself."
                                  userInfo:nil];
}
@end
```

**Private mutable subclass.**

Another option is to create an immutable class with the read-only accessors you want, and a private mutable subclass that has read-write accessors. You can implement `-copyWithZone:` in the mutable subclass so that you get an immutable object when you make a copy. This all amounts to about the same thing I described above -- either way, you're hiding the creation mechanism from the client.

Comment: I *think* this is not answering OP's question. He's not asking how to `alloc-init` an `SKDownload` instance. He wants to imitate the behavior of that class (i. e. `alloc-init` returns `nil`, only the owner and God know how to instantiate it.)

Comment: Yes, I understood that. This what I'm trying to replicate. I don't want my framework users to be able to instantiate some classes B, but I want them to be able to use classes B instances (that I may return my users via class methods).

Comment: @Nicolas The standard way of doing that is a private (non-exposted) initializer which does the proper initialization, and an overridden `init` which does `[self release]; return nil;`. You can't, however, **prevent** the user entirely from creating an instance - runtime introspection can be used at any time to find the secret initializer, and again, `class_createInstance()` works too.

Comment: But `+[SKDownload alloc]` and `-[SKDownload init]` *don't* return `nil`. The point is, you're not *supposed* to use them, but you *can*.

Comment: Thanks mipadi. I just tried and `+[SKDownload alloc] -[SKDownload init]` both return nil (`NSLog(@"%p", [SKDownload alloc]);` displays "0x0").

Comment: @H2CO3: Have you tested it? Because they definitely don't. Try out this code, you'll see: https://gist.github.com/mdippery/ba47be35bffcde0632a4

Comment: So if I understand correctly, B overrides its `init` and `alloc` methods to return nil and implements a custom hidden initializer (exposed in my private header but not in the public header), and A just uses the private header to call the custom initializer? Am I missing something or does it sound good to you guys?

Comment: @mipadi, this outputs `alloc: 0x0` and `init: 0x0` here. What am I missing?

Comment: Also, if B implements `alloc` to return nil, how will A be able to alloc it? (this may be okay with -init but alloc?!)

Comment: @Nicolas I've only told you that **twice** within the last 20 or so minutes >.< 1. As you see in the example, B does ***NOT*** override `alloc` to return `nil`. 2. Even if it did, `class_createInstance()` still works.

Comment: @Nicolas That'd do it, except that I wouldn't change `+alloc`. Just hiding the initializer should be enough for most purposes.

Comment: @H2CO3, yes and I thank you for that. I just want it to be clear. I may be stupid but how are the Apple folks managing this `+alloc` returning nil thing if they don't re-implement if but it's still returning nil?

Comment: @Nicolas: What code are you using to ascertain that `alloc` *is* returning `nil`?

Comment: @Nicolas ... please... **think...** They **do** override it. It's only this example that doesn't.

Comment: @H2CO3... I AM thinking, we are just saying the same thing. The question about the `+alloc` mentions your name but is open to everyone here. I understand that they DO override it, you are not giving me this answer but you gave 50% answers of my interrogations (and thank you again for the -init answer). I'm just wondering (not asking YOU personally since you obviously don't know) :) That is okay if my classes can be `alloc'ed` but not `init'ed` (better if they can't both, but that's just curiosity).

Comment: @Caleb, when you say that Apple hides the initialization mechanism, does this mean that if I were to investigate the SKDownload methods (via the Objc-runtime), I would certainly find a custom hidden initializer?

Comment: @Nicolas If you're interested in how `+alloc` works, and how to work around it, you might like to read Matt Gallagher's [Alternative Objective-C allocation for large arrays](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/08/alternative-objective-c-object.html). Think twice before actually *doing* this -- the chance that you'd actually need it are small, and the chance that it'll give you headaches is large. But it's nice to have some insight into how the whole thing works anyway.

Comment: @Nicolas Maybe, maybe not. Maybe they've written a plain old C function that constructs a fully-formed, initialized instance of `SKDownload`. Maybe the only initializer that exists in the wild is `-initWithCoder:` and valid objects can only be created by the iTunes servers. There are many possibilities, but the details don't really matter. What matters is what *you* are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Nicolas: Apple *doesn't* hide the initialization mechanism. You can still call `[[SKDownload alloc] init]`—but you *shouldn't*, according to the API, because those methods won't do anything interesting or useful.